# how do you tell P2WSH invoice addresses apart from P2SH?

Tags: segregated-witness, address-format, p2wsh

... and how do you tell P2WPKH invoice addresses apart from P2PKH?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- P2PKH addresses are 33-34 characters long, use Base58Check encoding, and (on mainnet) start with "1".
- P2SH addresses are 34 characters long, use Base58Check encoding, and (on mainnet) start with "3".
- P2WPKH addresses are 42 characters long, use bech32 encoding, and (on mainnet) start with "bc1q".
- P2WSH addresses are 62 characters long, use bech32 encoding, and (on mainnet) start with "bc1q".
- P2TR addresses (coming in november) are 62 characters long, use bech32m encoding, and (on mainnet) start with "bc1p".

P2SH-wrapped P2WSH exists too. These cannot be distinguished from other P2SH addresses, until they are spent.